# Codeigniter Nesting Loop error in connecting to database

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, codeigniter

I was going though the Codeigniter tutorial in the user guide but when I got to the section using the model I got an error saying that the execution timed out. I subsequently increased the php execution time to 1200 and the next error was the maximum nesting level has been been reached at 100, I have subsequently increased it to 200 with the same error.

It appears that its stuck in some kind of nesting loop just referencing the same 4 functions repeatedly.

I am running:
Codeigniter 3.0.0
Apache 2.4.9
PHP 5.5.12
SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB - (Windows Authentication - if that makes a difference)

Part of the Error Message Below:

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\www\NewsApp\system\database\DB_driver.php on line 963

Call Stack
    Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  151936  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0030  197064  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\NewsApp\system\core\CodeIgniter.php' )   ..\index.php:292
3   0.0360  850512  News->__construct( )    ..\CodeIgniter.php:500
4   0.0390  985568  CI_Loader->model( ) ..\News.php:7
5   0.0410  992936  News_model->__construct( )  ..\Loader.php:305
6   0.0410  993224  CI_Loader->database( )  ..\News_model.php:6
7   0.0420  1016048 DB( )   ..\Loader.php:349
8   0.0520  1612760 CI_DB_driver->initialize( ) ..\DB.php:216
9   0.0520  1612904 CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver->db_connect( )  ..\DB_driver.php:401
10  15.0609 1616496 CI_DB_driver->query( )  ..\sqlsrv_driver.php:147
11  15.0609 1616728 CI_DB_driver->simple_query( )   ..\DB_driver.php:642
12  15.0609 1616728 CI_DB_driver->initialize( ) ..\DB_driver.php:768
13  15.0609 1616728 CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver->db_connect( )  ..\DB_driver.php:401
14  30.0707 1617416 CI_DB_driver->query( )  ..\sqlsrv_driver.php:147
15  30.0707 1617560 CI_DB_driver->simple_query( )   ..\DB_driver.php:642
16  30.0707 1617560 CI_DB_driver->initialize( ) ..\DB_driver.php:768
17  30.0707 1617560 CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver->db_connect( )  ..\DB_driver.php:401
```

What's going on here?

The model:

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
    {
            if ($slug === FALSE)
            {
                    $query = $this->db->get('news');
                    return $query->result_array();
            }

            $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
            return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

Just $this->load->database(); is causing the loop.

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop of some kind. Could you post the contents of your model so that we can help identify it?

Comment: I could but this is happening just from loading the database

Comment: Please try adding `parent::__construct();`  to your current __construct() function - not sure if that will be the culprit but it should definitely be in there and may help us shed some light on it. At the moment, I cant see anything else that is out of place.

Comment: I added that and got the same error.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue with the exact same Codeigniter, Apache, PHP, SQL versions. It happened on upgrading from CI 2.2 to CI 3.0. The infinite loop appears to be caused by sqlsrv_driver.php lines 147 and 148...

Comment: I switched to Laravel. Sorry bro.